# relation between sheaf of hom and hom of sheaf

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

If $\mathcal{M，N}$ are the associated sheaf of $A$ modules $M$ and $N$ on $X=Spec A,$ then what is $\mathcal{Hom_{O_X}(M,N)}$？Is that the associated sheaf of $Hom(M,N)\ ?$

Comment: One is a sheaf, the other is a group. How could you ever have an example where they are the same?

Comment: I'm sorry its such a basic question.. You are right

Comment: If $\mathcal{M，N}$ are the associated sheaf of A modules M,N on X=Spec A, then what is $\mathcal{Hom_{O_X}(M,N)}$?

Comment: Module $M$ should be coherent.

Comment: How can I prove that?

Comment: Assume $M$ is finitely presented and prove that for any multiplicative set $$S^{-1}(Hom(M,N)) \cong Hom_{S^{-1}(A)}(S^{-1}(M), S^{-1}(N))$$. Then play the usual game with sheaves on a good base... Or just look it up in EGA or Hartshorne chapter 3 section on local Ext or any beginning book ...

Answer (score 8):

Just to give a few more details on Daniel's comments:

In general, $\mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N})$ is not the associated sheaf to $Hom_A(M,N)$. Simple example: Take $A = \mathbb{Z}$, $M = \mathbb{Z}[\frac12]$ and $N = \mathbb{Z}$. Then $Hom_A(M,N) = 0$, but the Hom-sheaf is non-zero evaluated at the non-vanishing locus of $2$ (also known as $Spec \mathbb{Z}[\frac12]$).

Now assume that $M$ is a finitely presented module. Since taking associated module is left adjoint to global sections, we have a canonical map
$$\widetilde{Hom_A(M,N)} \to \mathcal{H}om_{\mathcal{O}_X}(\mathcal{M},\mathcal{N}).$$ It is enough to show that this is an isomorphism on the standard opens $D(f)$ for $f \in A$. If we evaluate the source on $D(f)$, we get $Hom_A(M,N)[\frac 1f]$. If we evaluate the target on $D(f)$, we get $Hom_{A[\frac 1f]}(M[\frac1f], N[\frac1f]) \cong Hom_A(M, N[\frac1f])$. The localization $N[\frac1f]$ is isomorphic to the direct limit of

$$ N \xrightarrow{f\cdot} N \xrightarrow{f\cdot}\cdots. $$

Taking Hom out of a finitely presented module commutes with direct limits. Thus, $$Hom_A(M, N[\frac1f]) \cong Hom_A(M, N)[\frac1f]$$ as was to be shown.